# How do user actions carry across with migrated questions if the user is not in that community?

Tags: discussion, edits, migration

Lets say, to give this question a scenario, I edited a question to fix some grammar, but then later on some moderators migrated it to a new community, a community I haven't joined yet.

Am I automatically registered to that community, do my edits become anonymous, or does StackExchange have a system to link back even if I'm not associated?

Answer (score 4):

[This Big Meta FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/266187) contains most of what you need to know (interesting parts in italics):

> ### What is migration?
>
> Migration allows an off-topic question to be gracefully moved to
> another site in the Stack Exchange network. *It preserves the current
> revision of the question, all its answers, any comments on any post,
> as well as most of the votes.*
>
> #### Side effects of migration
>
> - ***Down votes are cleared** from the question upon its migration*
> - *If a user who has participated in the question does not have an account on the target site, their username is displayed as plain text
>   until they create an account*
> - **Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately** upon question migration (This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the
>   origin site.)
> - **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted (Again, this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.)

This should mean that any edits you do, will be preserved with your current name, but that's not the case ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208832/266187)):

> The older revisions are not destroyed and are still present on the original (albeit deleted) answer on the source site. However, migration only transfers the current version of each post to the destination site. So the new site would only have one revision of each post, as if they had never been edited.

Edits are not moved to the target site, but are still present on the origin site through a back link. The question stub is still there, but 30 days after migration it is (soft) deleted so that you need 10K reputation to see your edits.

Comments are kept as is and will be correctly associated with you as soon as you create an account on the target site.

Upvotes are a little trickier, because they won't be associated to your (new) account on the target site, so you can vote twice on the same question and answers ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20208/266187)).

---

The whole thing of missing edit migrations is sort of a gray legal area. See: [Does the migration of edited posts violate attribution requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208904/266187)